# Default redirect in mod_rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Simple question... According to this tutorial: [URL Rewriting](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) I´d like to make a simple redirect rule. I´m working on my testserver, so the website is in a subdirectory of the domain: http://my-server.de/lcbs . I like to redirect http://my-server.de/lcbs/index to http://my-server.de/lcbs/index.php?page=news&parent=lcbs. So I´m using this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^lcbs/index?$ lcbs/index.php?page=news&parent=lcbs
```

Now, when I like to open http://my-server.de/lcbs/index , this error appears:

```
The requested URL /lcbs/index was not found on this server.
```

If I change it to following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index?$ index.php?page=news&parent=lcbs
```

this error appears:

```
The requested URL /var/www/lcbs.de/public_html/index.php was not found on this server.
```

What I´m doing wrong? I think it´s not a big thing...
Thanks!

Comment: What is the intention of the `?` near the end of the `RewriteRule` _pattern_?

Comment: @w3dk To answer the comment - I forgot the slash, for optional slash at the end of the url. So: `RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php?page=lcbs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /lcbs/
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php?page=news&parent=lcbs
```

or this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^lcbs/index$ lcbs/index.php?page=news&parent=lcbs
```

Comment: The first solution creates an Server Internal Error and the whole website is not reachable by this error. The second one shows the Not found exception "The requested URL /lcbs/index was not found on this server." ... I try to find it out by looking thru the logs ...

Comment: The 500 error is caused by the invalid argument to the `RewriteBase` directive - which must start with a slash. However, if the OPs code didn't work, then these aren't going to either (they are basically the same).

Comment: Thanks! Yes the slash was the problem! Now it´s working

Comment: I've updated my answer and added the missing leading slash.